# How do I get more image editing options in the admin?

Tags: images, post-thumbnails

In an installation of Wordpress 4.7, when I go to edit an Media | Library | Some Image | Edit Image I am offered editing options such as, "Restore Original Image" and "Thumbnail Settings".

[image: thumbnail editing options]

However in my other installation of Wordpress 4.5 I do not have any thumbnail setting options and it's related "restore" option.

[image: no thumbnail optinos]

My question, is this a theme setting issue? Is this a version issue? How do I activate or get these thumbnail options. Additionally, I need to clarify that this problem is only occurring on some images within a specific installation and specific theme.

Comment: I tested out another installation of WP 4.5.3 and the thumbnail settings DO appear there. So it should not be based on version after all. It is a setting issue?

Comment: You should upgrade your 4.5.3 installs to 4.7, any answer will assume the latest version of WordPress ( and if it's only on 4.7 installs you see this option then it's clearly something that was added after 4.5 ). If this only happens with a certain theme then you need to contact the theme support, we don't provide theme support here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There actually is no way to "add" additional image editing features like "Thumbnail settings" in WP. It turns out the discrepancy for my problem was due to an inability to create thumbnails (at least by default) on GIFs in Wordpress 4.5.3.

Answer (score 3):

This is correct. To have the **Restore Original Image**, you need to alter the image first.

Also for the thumbnails, if `if ( $thumb && $sub_sizes )` condition is not met (if the image doesn't have thumbs) you will not see the thumbnails section.

```
File: wp-admin/includes/image-edit.php
143:    <?php if ( $thumb && $sub_sizes ) {
144:        $thumb_img = wp_constrain_dimensions( $thumb['width'], $thumb['height'], 160, 120 );
145:    ?>
```

BTW, WordPress 4.5 Coleman, has been released 2016-04-12.
You simple [track the changes](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/commits/285a774cadbd7d1f858776c9b9a300b6b58deac6/wp-admin/includes/image-edit.php) and nothing serious happened from then till now.

---

For instance, I created a really small image 5x10px, and when I enter the edit section I don't get the thumbnail section. Image too small.

[image: No thumbnails section]

---

You may [add](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/)

```
add_image_size( string $name, int $width, int $height, bool|array $crop = false )
```

inside your theme. Low values for *width* and *height* may inject the thumbnail section.

---

This [post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/251683/cropping-an-image-before-inserting-into-a-post/251699#251699) is not super relevant but it may help.

Comment: I'm not sure if your assessment regarding thumbnails is correct (if image doesn't have thumbs you will not see thumbnails section). I created a third install of WP 4.5.3. I uploaded an image and it is showing the thumbnails options automatically when I go to "edit image".

Comment: Aha, after you upload the image @rpeg, the thumbnails of a specific size may be created based on the theme or plugins you use. Mostly based on the theme instructions. For super small images, there may not be thumbnails at all.

Comment: @rpeg, there are other cases, maybe, but I tested for the image 5x10px and I don't see this part with thumbnails. I will [edit] the post.

Comment: If it's a theme issue, which is part of my original post, should I ask a new question on how to resolve this theme issue? I can't find documentation on how to enable/disable this feature.

Comment: One image in question, that doesn't have the thumb settings, is 1440x880. In fact for some reason the image breaks when I go to "Edit Image" but I'll save that concern for another time - http://imgur.com/SpFlHi8

Comment: One last note and I should consider adding this to my OP, this problem is occurring on SOME images. Not all.

Comment: @rpeg, very precise you said that. You may ask the new question anytime. I just tried to provide you the idea how one may try to understand this problem. I will update just one minor detail in my answer.

Comment: thanks for your help. This has proven to be a very confusing issue.

Comment: @rpeg, strange but I think it is not confusing, just focus on `wp-admin/includes/image-edit.php` conditions and you are good.

Comment: I'll do that. I did ANOTHER test. On WP 4.5.3 and using a copy of the theme with the problem, I uploaded an image. It works! So this problem is specific to a WP installation on a specific host so far...

Comment: This is interesting. Try to enable the debug log in WordPress. Sometimes [debug logs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) show very relevant details.

Comment: Found the solution. Might be dumb. Thumbnail settings don't work on Gifs. That's it.